# Is it possible to install Vista from a flash drive?

Tags: windows-vista, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

I'm looking to reformat my laptop that is running Vista, and I had planned on burning an ISO to a DVD-R and installing Vista to the laptop from that after reformatting, but I don't have any blank DVD-R and was wondering if it is possible to do the same thing from a flash drive, just burning to ISO to it and installing from there. If not, is there a way to do it without using a DVD-R?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool for windows that allows you to easily burn an ISO image to a USB device.  It can be found here:
http://rufus.akeo.ie/

It provides a simple interface for you to select the ISO image and the USB device to burn to.  After burning, just select the USB device from the boot menu.

Answer (score -1):

A vista forum have done this:

It involves extracting the Vista ISO and putting the contents onto the USB and making it bootable.

Read more: http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/181538-usb-bootable-vista-installation-flash-thumb-drive.html